# The Google Optimize snippet for the container with ID GTM-... is not correctly installed on this page

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize

I'm trying to use Google Optimise with Analytics installed by gtag.js and am getting errors in some parts of the Optimise UI but not others.

Here's what I've done:

1. Installed Google Analytics following the instructions ["Set up Analytics tracking with gtag.js"](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en) (and confirmed it's working by using the Real-Time Preview).
2. Set up Google Analytics following the instructions ["Deploy Optimize using Global Site Tag (gtag.js)"](https://support.google.com/360suite/optimize/answer/7513085)
3. Added the [page-hiding snippet](https://support.google.com/360suite/optimize/answer/7100284).

When I **set up** an experiment using the Chrome extension, Optimise appears to be running as Google expect - notice that there's no number shown by the exclamation mark icon in the screenshot below (there is if I remove the Optimise code), and clicking it says "no issues detected".  (Also, the chrome extension's icon doesn't have any error symbol.)

[image: Google Optimise Chrome extension without errors]

However, if I then **preview** either the original or the variant (clicking the "screen" icon in Optimise), I get a javascript alert which says:

> The Google Optimize snippet for the container with ID GTM-abcdef is not correctly installed on this page. To preview variants for this experiment, make sure the Google Optimize snippet is installed on any pages you want to test.

(I've replaced my actual container ID by "abcdef" in the above.)

And the Chrome extension icon also shows an error and a similar message when clicked (I've blacked out the experiment name here):

[image: Google Optimise Chrome extension icon with error]

Here's my HTML `<head>` section (with IDs redacted):

I've compared the script from this with the example in ["Deploy Optimize using Global Site Tag (gtag.js)"](https://support.google.com/360suite/optimize/answer/7513085) and they appear identical except that my code contains real IDs:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- Page hiding snippet (recommended)  -->
    <style>.async-hide { opacity: 0 !important} </style>
    <script>(function(a,s,y,n,c,h,i,d,e){s.className+=' '+y;h.start=1*new Date;
    h.end=i=function(){s.className=s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?'+y),'')};
    (a[n]=a[n]||[]).hide=h;setTimeout(function(){i();h.end=null},c);h.timeout=c;
    })(window,document.documentElement,'async-hide','dataLayer',4000,
    {'GTM-zyxzyx':true});</script>

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-abcdef"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'UA-abcdef', { 'optimize_id': 'GTM-zyxzyx'});      
    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>
```

I've tried this against a site running locally (on Flask's webserver, port 5000) and against a site deployed onto Heroku, and behaviour is the same in both instances.

I've also tried removing the page-hiding snippet code, but that didn't help.

I've also tried actually running the experiment but always saw the original variant even when setting the alternative one to have 100% traffic, so it's not working there.  (I only tried this against local site, haven't tried against the Heroku instance.)

It's worth noting that there's this line in the GA code:

```
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
```

I've seen it online in that form and with the semi-colon at the end:

```
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
```

I've tried both without any effect.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, will let you know if we figure out what's going on. Did optimize work for you previously? In our case we've successfully used it for many tests in the past, but it's now not detecting the Optimize snippet.

Comment: Glad it's not just me, @shirajg.  This is the first time I've used Optimize, in fact, so don't have previous experience to compare to.

Comment: I tried it out in an incognito window, and it seems to work properly. I think I had a plugin interfering with it. I haven't taken the time to isolate which one, but I noticed in your screenshot that you have lastPass installed as well, so maybe that's it.

Comment: Thanks @shirajg.  I won't have a chance to try this for a while, but I'll give your suggestion a go next time I'm working on this.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: In the end, we used Google Tag Manager to add Analytics and Optimise to the site, since that was what the client was using elsewhere.  So I don't have an answer to this, I'm afraid, @Notflip.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is correct, but should the hiding snippet be using the ID UA-abcdef?

> If you’re using Google Tag Manager to deploy Optimize, populate the
>   page-hiding snippet with your Tag Manager container ID, not your
>   Optimize container ID. Learn more about using Optimize with a
>   tag-management system (from here: https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7100284?hl=en)

I'm not sure whether deploying the code this way is classed as deploying Optimize with Google Tag Manager though. What do others think?